# Cannot create a copy of an integer pointer. It is always a reference

Tags: c++, pointers

Just as the question suggest, I cannot make a copy of the `int* cells` variable.

I have tried:

```cpp
int * newCells = *cells // this a compile error
```

I have tried:

```cpp
memcpy()
```

this still makes it a reference

```
int* cellCompete(int* cells, int days)
{
    // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
    
    //make a copy of the cells
    int* newCells = cells;
    newCells[0] = 29;
    cout << "TEST: " << newCells[0] << endl;
    cout << "TEST 2: " << cells[0] << endl;

 }
```

This will print out:

```
TEST: 29
TEST 2: 29
```

Comment: A pointer and an integer are different things. You _did_ copy the pointer. It's an _exact_ copy, including that points at the same `int` as the first pointer.

Comment: how would I copy it without changing the original when I change the copy?

Comment: A fresh copy of the array itself, you mean?

Comment: In that case, you _don't_ want a copy of the pointer. You want a copy of the `int`(s?), and a completely new pointer that points at those `int`s.

Comment: Yes I think @bipll I would like to change the copy without affecting the original "cells" array. so If I change the newCells[0] to 29 then the original cells should be what it was before

Comment: This is not how you copy an array in C++.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: The title says "*copy of an integer pointer*", and that's what the code does. If you mean a copy of the integer itself, instead, then just take `*cells` and store it somewhere else.

Comment: @devin if you want to make a copy of the array, then you have to actually allocate a new array and copy the values of the old array into it.  Then you can modify the copied array all you want

Comment: I tried this @RemyLebeau this ended in a compile error

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You don't want a copy of an integer pointer. You want a completely different pointer to a completely different part of memory that is a copy of some other part of memory.

Comment: @devin You are not making a copy of the array itself at all, only copying the *pointer* to the array. You need something more like this instead: `int* newCells = new int[N]; std::copy(cells, cells+N, newCells); newCells[0] = 29; ... delete[] newCells;` where `N` is the size of the old array. This would be much simpler if you used `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of a C-style array pointer.

Comment: It seems like you're mentally conflating a pointer with the thing that it points at.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think you answered my question. And yes I usually always use a vector or an array but this question has required me to use pointers which I haven't used since I was 15. I am 25 now. So, it's been a little while. I also don't remember this being a thing in c++ and more in C. Pointers are very confusing to me still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just as the question suggest, I cannot make a copy of the int* cells variable.

You can, and you did make a copy of the `int* cells` variable.

The variable is a pointer. When you copy a pointer, you get another pointer that points to the same object that the original points to. Since both pointer variables point to the same object, modifying that object through one pointer will be seen when that same object is observed through the other pointer.

If you want to make a copy of the pointed object, you need to indirect through the pointer.

> ```
> int * newCells = *cells
> ```

This is in the right direction. But the object pointed by pointer to integer is not a pointer to integer. The object pointed by pointer to integer is an integer. So, you must change the type of the variable that is to hold the copy of that integer:

```
int newCells = *cells;
```

Comment: I tried to do int * newCells = *cells and this was an error to the compiler

Comment: @devin Read the last paragraph of my answer again.

Comment: @devin If you want a copy of the entire array, you first need to create a new one of appropriate size with `new` (preferably) or `malloc` and then copy the data into this new array with `std::copy` (preferably) or `memcpy` (note that either of these only copies from source to destination, neither one allocates memory!). In any case, you should seriously consider using a `std::vector` instead which relieves you of all this trouble.